# Issue in converting .mov to .mp4 php

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, exec

I am trying to convert a video with extension .mov to .mp4 format. Following is the command that I try to use

```
$file_name = "abc.mov";

$mp4_file  = "abc.mp4";

$cmd = 'sudo /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /path_to_file' . $file_name . ' -strict experimental -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -preset slower -crf 18 -vf "scale=trunc(in_w/2)*2:trunc(in_h/2)*2" /destination_path/' . $mp4_file;
exec($cmd, $out, $res);
```

However the desired file( with .mp4 ) is not getting created. When I copy the command and paste it inside terminal, the file with the desired format is getting created. However same is not working with exec command in my php code.

I am not able to figure out the actual cause of issue, since it seems out to be strange. Any help shall be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked `exec()`s return value for error messages?

Comment: The `user` trying to `exec` the command likely doesn't have the privileges to use the `sudo` command.

Comment: Even If i do it without sudo command, still it doesn't work. Also the the exec command is returning nothing.

Comment: Also note that it is only happening for .mov and not for other file types

Comment: `/path_to_file' . $file_name` Are you sure you are not missing a `/` here ? I know this is just an example, but here, if `$file_name` only contains the file name without path, the concatenation will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a '2&>1' at the end of the exec?

Answer (score -1):

Use this code it Work's for me :)

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -preset slow -crf 22 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: There is no code there, this is just a command line invocation of ffmpeg, which, as the OP said, works for him. It is the call to exec from PHP that does not yield the desired result.

Comment: You can try with system() instead of exec().

Comment: system executes an external program and display the output... This is not really equivalent to exec. Displaying ffmpeg's output to the user is more than often not something desirable.